# Jenkins attempts to build from tomcat root, and not JENKINS_HOME

Tags: git, tomcat, jenkins

I recently moved my Jenkins install from a standalone configuration to within Tomcat, and when attempting to run a pipeline build, it fails during the initial Git Checkout phase (as posted in the below shell output) it attempts to initialize from the home directory for Tomcat on my Ubuntu VM (/usr/share/tomcat7), and not the defined JENKINS_HOME (in this case /var/lib/jenkins).

```
Started by user joel
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mediawiki/workspace
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Beginning Wiki build process
[Pipeline] git
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:ghostfreeman/lpg_mediawiki.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:ghostfreeman/lpg_mediawiki.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Key
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:ghostfreeman/lpg_mediawiki.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:ghostfreeman/lpg_mediawiki.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:797)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1051)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1082)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:ghostfreeman/lpg_mediawiki.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Could not create directory '/usr/share/tomcat7/.ssh'.
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/usr/share/tomcat7/.ssh/known_hosts).
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1752)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1495)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:795)
    ... 13 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

The Tomcat home directory is limited to root access only, which i'm sure is by design. I would much rather prefer the operation executed from the project's build/workspace directory within JENKINS_HOME. I have Tomcat configured to define JENKINS_HOME to the directory where I have builds and workspaces defined, but it is going ignored for reasons that aren't obvious to me. Did I miss something in setting up Jenkins on Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by creating the needed .ssh directory within the tomcat home dir, with access roles assigned to the Tomcat user on the system. All build processes proceed to function within JENKINS_HOME, as intended.